# Getting integers from text file and work on array list in java

Tags: java, arrays, file, arraylist, io

> I have text file which is contains:
> " I have 3 apples and 1 banana.
> All people have 4 cars at least."
>
> I want to read this .txt file and get integers from it.I will strore integer variables in arrayList.

```
public class dedede {
    public static void al() throws Exception {

        File f = new File("C:\\users\\sony\\Desktop\\456.txt");

        try {
            FileReader islem = new FileReader(f);

            char data[] = new char[(int) f.length()];

            islem.read(data);
            String metin = new String(data);

            ArrayList<Integer> yapi = new<Integer> ArrayList();

            StringTokenizer s = new StringTokenizer(metin);

            String dizi[] = new String[s.countTokens()];

            int i = 0;
            while (s.hasMoreTokens()) {
                dizi[i] = s.nextToken();
                i++;
            }

            for (int c = 0; c < dizi.length; c++) {
                if (Integer.parseInt(dizi[c]) > 0) {
                    yapi.add(Integer.parseInt(dizi[c]));
                }

            }

            System.out.println(yapi);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        al();
    }
}
```

Comment: What issue/problem are you experiencing?

Comment: i want to program read file recognize integers and store them in a array.

Comment: In addition to your code, you should give some indication of the problem you are having when you run it or any question you have about your results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
static ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        File file = new File("C:\\users\\sony\\Desktop\\456.txt");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String s; 
        while ((s = in.readLine()) != null) {
            findInteger(s);
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("File Read Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    System.out.println("Integers: " + al);
}

private static void findInteger(String s){
    String [] parts = s.split(" ");

    for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
        try{
            int j = Integer.parseInt(parts[i]);
            al.add(j);
        } catch (Exception e){}
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you .you have been very helpfull i just missed something really simple stuff :)